# Цвет выбранного item

Tags: java, android, listview, background

Как изменить задний фон у выбранного item в listview ? Не при нажатии, а именно постоянно и только у одного.

> UP

Все в ListFragmet происходит. Делаю так:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Если, например, выбрать первый в списке, то он красит, помимо него, каждый первый на "новом экране" при скроле.

> Решил, но не до конца

При создании SimpleAdapter указал

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2
```

В коде так

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //В других местах, в том числе в разметке не работает,
    //только в тут
    getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    l.setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

Осталось разобраться как изменить дефолтный синий цвет выделения...

> Вопрос закрыт

Изменить цвет помог следующий гайд [тык](http://motzcod.es/post/108837945597/fixing-activatedbackgroundindicator-in-appcompat)

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted)

Comment: Написать свой адаптер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListView listView;
listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyListener);
class MyListener implemenet AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
   onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        view.setBackground(fee);
   }
}
```

Вот псевдокод, если я правильно понял, что значит "для выбранного элемента".